# Resources.resx modification leads to toolStrip problems

Tags: c#, resources, toolstrip

In my project a have an `toolStrip` element which behaves strange after modification in Resources.resx file. Doesn't matter what I do: add a new `bitmap`, delete old `bitmap`, change `Display style of dropdown buttons`... Every time I got error messages and no `toolStrip` at the form.

In my `Form.Designer.cs` happens next:

Before modification code looks like:

```
        // 
        // toolStrip1
        //             
        this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1,
        this.toolStripSeparator4,
        this.toolStripDropDownButton2});
        this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
        this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1584, 27);
        this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 347;
        this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
```

After:

```
    // 
    // toolStrip1
    //      
    this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
    this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1584, 27);
    this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 347;
    this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
```

My DropDownButton before modification:

```
        // 
        // toolStripDropDownButton1
        // 
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.openFileToolStripMenuItem,
        this.saveCalculationsFileToolStripMenuItem,
        this.saveRawCalculationsFileToolStripMenuItem});
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Image = global::Project_Tribo_v._0._2.Properties.Resources.folder_document;
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Name = "toolStripDropDownButton1";
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 24);
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "File";
```

And after:

```
            // 
            // toolStripDropDownButton1
            //                 
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Image = global::Project_Tribo_v._0._2.Properties.Resources.folder_document;
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Name = "toolStripDropDownButton1";
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 24);
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "File";
```

It's not a big problem, while I have small number of toolStrip elements, but stil...

Any ideas how to avoid or repair this?

Comment: Are you modifying...what? Designer generated resx/cs? If it's the case then just don't do it...

Comment: Any modifications leads to the problem. Even if I just change the text in textbox by properties field.

Comment: I mean: are you manually chaning designer generated resx/cs files? If this is what you're doing then: DO NOT DO IT. If it happens when modifying form from within designer then it's another issue (but I can't imagine what).

Comment: The designer isn't that resilient to doing this.  Non-zero odds that you'll cause an exception at design time because a control is using a resource that is not longer available.  And yes, you'll lose parts of your design when that happens.